# Python loop define limits trouble

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I am newbie in Python ...
I am dealing with an array of 10 elements A[0,10]
 trying to do this loop:

```
for i in range(1, 9):
    C.append((A[i+1]-A[i-1])/2)
```

to find the average value of each point...

afterwards If I wish to print the results :

```
print(i, A[i], C[i])
print(i, A[i], C[i-2])
```

the second print is only working, the first is not.. please why this?
And I need also to define the first and the last value of C[1] and C[10] 
and I can't do that because the first value is the C[-2] which is C[9] ...

if someone has any idea how to solve it....

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.  I'm afraid that I am having a little trouble following your question.  You can edit it to make it more clear.  Come up with a minimum working example that we can run and see exactly what is happening.  That might help us to understand your confusion.

Comment: You need to explain what "not working" means.  What do you want it to do, and what is it doing instead?

Answer (score 2):

It's not usual to iterate over python lists (and I assume you mean a `list`) by index. 
You're operating on pairs of items, so a more idiomatic way to do this would be:

```
for prev, next in zip(a, a[2:]):
    # do whatever
```

Look up `zip` in the standard documentation. The two variables are assigned from the results of `zip` using *sequence assignment*, which is just where a comma-separated list of variables is bound to the elements of a sequence.

The second thing you're doing that is unidiomatic is to append to a list in a loop. This sort of thing is so common that python has a specific syntax for it:

```
[(next - prev)/2 for prev, next in zip(a, a[2:])]
```

This is called a *list comprehension*. If you can't guess what that does after pasting it into the interpreter, read about it in the standard documentation and the many articles available via google.

That code in action;

```
>>> import random
>>> a = range(5,15)
>>> random.shuffle(a)
>>> a
[11, 5, 12, 14, 6, 7, 8, 13, 10, 9]
>>> [(next - prev)/2 for prev, next in zip(a, a[2:])]
[0, 4, -3, -4, 1, 3, 1, -2]
>>>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and you time to help me.. I have lot to read! that's for sure! :) ... just sometimes I find my self to be lost on the chaotic results of google about one problem ...

Answer (score 1):

You use symmetric difference to find `C` but the edge points (0,9) have only one neighbor. You could fix it by using left, right differences for edge points:

```
n = len(A) # 10 in your case
C = [0.] * n

if n > 1:
   C[0] = (A[1] - A[0]) / 2.
   C[-1] = (A[-1] - A[-2]) / 2.

for i in xrange(1, n-1):
    C[i] = (A[i+1] - A[i-1]) / 2.
```

Whether it is appropriate depends on how you'd like to use the `C` list later.

If you need `C[0] = C[1]` then it is even simpler:

```
n = len(A)
C = [0.] * n

for i in xrange(1, n-1):
    C[i] = (A[i+1] - A[i-1]) / 2.

if n > 1:
   C[0] = C[1]
   C[-1] = C[-2] # for symmetry
```

if `n == 0` i.e., A is empty then C is empty.

if `n == 1` i.e., A has exactly one element then C has exactly one element: `C[0] = 0.`

Comment: Firstly,I am sorry for the not fluent English.Thank you for your welcome.I am newbie to Python and to be honest I mess it up a little.
J.F yes your code is working! excellent idea of using -1, so simple. I was trying instead to use i-1 (n-1)..
Just, I didn't mention that I need to have the C[0] = C[1], as an upper limit for the program. I will add it logically after C[-1],right?
What C does, is to find the average value of neighborly points of A LIST. Later I will use C and D to create a new list E and their symmetry was wrong.Now it's solved.THANK you all for ALL for your help & your time

Comment: just curious .. why you use if n>1 ? ... you could define C[1] and C[0] later ... I understand that is the right way, just why you do that? for remain symmetry ?

Answer (score 0):

Python lists are always indexed starting at 0. If you do

```
c = []         # c is a list
c.append(3)    # append 3 to the end of the list
print c        # => [3]
print c[0]     # => 3
```

So your code is putting (A[0]+A[2])/2 into C[0], then (A[1]+A[3])/2 into C[1], etc.

You might want create C as a list containing the appropriate number of 0s first, like

```
c = [0.]*10    # create a 10-item list

# calculate smoothed values from a
for i in xrange(1,9):
    c[i] = 0.25*a[i-1] + 0.5*a[i] + 0.25*a[i+2]

# clean up the ends
c[0] = 0.75*a[0] + 0.25*a[1]
c[9] = 0.25*a[8] + 0.75*a[9]
```

Comment: thanks for your help and your time to help me ... I have to fix few mistakes I have done to my program until now.